# OR operator multiple choices JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using this code for a X 'n' O file. What I have done is an IF statement with NOT option but using `||` operator I want to define multiple choices. That states the problem here. Please help me. Code below:

```
if (!xslot=="1" || !xslot=="2" || !xslot=="3" || !xslot=="4" || !xslot=="5" || !xslot=="6" || !xslot=="7" || !xslot=="8" || !xslot=="9") {
alert("Please enter a valid slot number from 1 to 9.");
}
```

Great thanks to anyone who helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to work with numbers, treat the input as a number :

```
if(+xslot < 1 || +xslot > 9) 
    alert("Please enter a valid slot number from 1 to 9.");
```

`+xslot` force the conversion to an int of `xslot`...

Comment: Actually this one works well! Thanks @SamuelCaillerie.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

var xslot = 15;
if (arr.indexOf(xslot) == -1) {
  alert('xslot is not in range')
};
```

You could also use ***[$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)***

Answer (score 2):

If you're only checking a number in range, try this snippet:

```
var i_xslot = parseInt(xslot, 10);
if (i_xslot < 1 || i_xslot > 9) {
  alert("Please enter a valid slot number from 1 to 9.");
}
```